# Insert an array of images with PDFMake

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, image, pdfmake

I have an array of images in base64 format called *imgFinding*. And I want to insert all of those images dynamically in pdf by using pdfmake. Below is a sample of my codes.

```
getDocumentDefinition() {
    let imgFinding = []
    for (var j = 0; j < this.images.length; j++) {
          imgFinding.push(this.images[j])
    }

    var dd = {
      content: [
       {
          image: imgFinding[0],
          width: 300
       }
      ],
    }
    return dd
  }
```

Based on the codes, I need to insert the image manually. How can I do it dynamically? Because the number of images that I need to insert is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built a list with suitable objects and put it insite of the content.

```
getDocumentDefinition() {
    let imgFinding = []
    for (var j = 0; j < this.images.length; j++) {
          imgFinding.push({image: this.images[j], width: 300})
    }

    var dd = {
      content: [
         imgFinding
      ],
    }
    return dd
  }
```